# Different JSON repsonse when using requests module in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to get JSON response from this [URL](https://www.bigbasket.com/product/get-products/?slug=fruits-vegetables&page=1&tab_type=[%22all%22]&sorted_on=popularity&listtype=pc).

But the JSON I see in the browser is different than what I get from python's requests response.

The code and its output:-

```
#code
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.bigbasket.com/product/get-products/?slug=fruits-vegetables&page=1&tab_type=[%22all%22]&sorted_on=popularity&listtype=pc")
print("Status code: ", r.status_code)
print("JSON: ", r.json())
print("Headers:\n",r.headers())

#output
Status code: 200
JSON: '{"cart_info": {}, "tab_info": [], "screen_name": ""}'
Headers:
{'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Content-Length': '52', 
'Server': 'nginx',
 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 
'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://b2b.bigbasket.com', 
'Date': 'Sat, 02 Sep 2017 18:43:51 GMT', 
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Set-Cookie': '_bb_cid=4; Domain=.bigbasket.com; expires=Fri, 28-Aug-2037 18:43:51 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/, ts="2017-09-03 00:13:51.164"; Domain=.bigbasket.com; expires=Sun, 02-Sep-2018 18:43:51 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/, _bb_rd=6; Domain=.bigbasket.com; expires=Sun, 02-Sep-2018 18:43:51 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/'}
```

This is what Chrome shows in dev tools:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 4206
Server: nginx
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://b2b.bigbasket.com
Date: Sat, 02 Sep 2017 15:43:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: ts="2017-09-02 21:13:20.193"; Domain=.bigbasket.com; expires=Sun, 02-Sep-2018 15:43:20 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/
Set-Cookie: _bb_rd=6; Domain=.bigbasket.com; expires=Sun, 02-Sep-2018 15:43:20 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/
```

Also tried separating query string and specifying it as params argument but it is giving the same result.

Comment: It seems that the first time you visit that address, it redirects you; though, every subsequent time you are not redirected. Have you tried making the request again?

Comment: What's the content of the browser response? I see the same almost empty JSON in my browser.

Comment: You have to get cookies first. Use `requests.Session`

Comment: This is the JSON I get from browser: https://pastebin.com/FSNuw3AA

Comment: Yes, if you delete your cookies you'll get the same response as with your code untill you reload the page.

Comment: @t.m.adam Yes, that totally works! Please paste it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: But what was the need to create a Session? This was my first time using requests. Do I need to do this every time?

Comment: Not every time, only if you have to handle cookies and keep-alive connections. You can learn more about it here: [session-objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

Comment: @t.m.adam I get it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
s.get("https://www.bigbasket.com/product/get-products/?slug=fruits-vegetables&page=1&tab_type=[%22all%22]&sorted_on=popularity&listtype=pc")
r = s.get("https://www.bigbasket.com/product/get-products/?slug=fruits-vegetables&page=1&tab_type=[%22all%22]&sorted_on=popularity&listtype=pc")
print("Status code: ", r.status_code)
print("JSON: ", r.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of different City ID identified by your web browser and Requests.
You can check value of _bb_cid in both the cases